# URL rewrite HTTP to HTTPS with one specific exception

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a payment page on my website: **domain.com/user/payment/product_name** and I want to be sure that all requests that come to this page will be redirected to HTTPS in htaccess.  "product_name" is an argument.

This is my current code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond ^([^/]+)/payment/([^/]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/payment/$2 [R=301,L]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Also I want that if a user open a page using HTTPS to any page, except payment page, to be redirected to HTTP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  off
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/payment/([a-zA-Z0-9\-])(/?.*)$  https://domain.com/$1/payment/$2$3  [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to say that "product_name" it's an argument

Comment: and what if "user" it's also an argument/variable?!

Comment: what characters are allowed in user name?

Comment: anychar, so I suppose i can use
RewriteRule ^(.*)/payment/([a-zA-Z0-9\-])(/?.*)$  https://domain.com/$1/payment/$2$3  [R=301,L,QSA]